# Django DB cyclic model prevention Queryset

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset

I am working on a project where I need have cyclic entries.
Think, a recipe might have a sub recipe and that might have a sub recipe.
The issue is one of those sub recipes might have its parents' parent as a child.

So I am trying to prevent this or at least not wanting to have to proved the user with an option to select that item.

To do this. I wanted to check on the server side if there is cycle.
A classic loop detection. So I was going to either implement BFS or DFS, possible DFS to minimize the memory usage and check each child and their child and so forth until I visit all nodes and keep a visited dict to keep the ids of all the models entries I see.

The issue is queryset is not providing some of the basic functions to do pop and push.

I can convert the query set to list but that could be expensive and run out of memory. It is unlikely to have 100000 depth recipe but in theory it can happen.

Is there an alternative to this?

I was thinking maybe pass the visited list to filter function so I constantly get filtered queryset of what I visited. Not sure if that is the right approach either.

Answer (score 0):

Loops can be easier detected if you traverse the graph from a node to its parents, not to its children, because some node can have many children, but usually not too many parents. A sub recipe has probably only on parent recipe or maybe you consider also a combined recipe of two recipes.

It is not necessary to analyze the whole graph each time. You can verify the complete integrity initially and later you verify only the modified nodes. (A new node is never a parent of any node and therefore it can also never create a loop.)

A model with one parent is trivial. It requires only a simple loop until you find a node without a parent.

If more parents are possible then a Breadth-first Search algorithm (BFS) is definitely better because you can easily select all parent nodes of the same level together by one query.

You can also prohibit a recipe that has e.g. more than 1000 ancestors including indirect ancestors because so much ancestors seems a nonsense for a recipe. That means that memory is not a problem. Maybe you also restrict the depth to 100 because it equals the number of necessary queries.

```py
def detect_loop(node):
    visited = {node.pk}
    analyzing = [node.pk]
    while analyzing:
        analyzing = TheModel.objects.filter(pk__in=analyzing).values_list('parents',
                                                                          flat=True)
        if visited.intersection(analyzing) or len(visited) + len(analyzing) > 1000:
            return True  # a loop or too much ancestors
        visited.update(analyzing)
    return False  # no loop defected
```